# Sharing session variables between asp.net and java

Tags: c#, java, visual-studio-2010, jsp, c#-4.0

My login page is in asp.net. I want to share session between various pages which are in java as well as `asp.net`. I even want to clear the session when user logouts from any of these pages.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnetinterop/archive/2006/03/20/sharing-session-state-between-jsp-and-asp-net.aspx?Redirected=true

Comment: "share session" as in "share content of ASP.Net session state" or have the same shared ID for otherwise unrelated session storage on ASP.Net and JSP servers? Also is it the same server (or more importantly site domain name) or different?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this, of many ways. You can send one token(GUID) generated in asp.net aplication to Java pages, after do that this you can verify token when the session exist in asp.net. When the user click for logout in java page, you redirect to a page in asp.net and execute the comand for erase this session. 
Hope Help you.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to transfer data is by turning it into a JSON string and then posting it to the new page, which will in turn populate variables and/or objects with values in the JSON string.

Apologies for the quickness answer. I intend to revisit this answer in the future and add an example to help user3225045's specific issue.

This should at least send them on the correct road though.

In C# I use 'Newtonsoft JSON' and I use 'minimal-json' in Java.

(Alternatives are probably available)

Note: This answer will work for sending messages between pages managed by all manner of different languages.